# Как запустить функцию, написанную на php

Tags: php

```
function donateUser() {
    $a = $_SESSION['id'];
    global $link;
    $sql = "UPDATE `users` SET `user_balance` = `user_balance` -'$wastedBalance' WHERE `user_id` = $a";
    $result = mysqli_query($link, $sql);

    $users = mysqli_fetch_all ($result, 1) ;
    return $users;

}
```

Как привязать ее к кнопке что-бы при нажатии выполнялся данный код, если `<a onclick="donateUser();" class="orange_button money">Подтвердить</a>` не работает

Comment: `onclick` только для JavaScript'a, оно не запускает РНР-код

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Данная функция на `php`. В ссылке `onclick="donateUser();"` код js. Здесь есть, наверное, такие варианты:

1.Задать прямую ссылку на файл со скриптом php

Например:

```
<a href="donate-user.php" class="orange_button money">Подтвердить</a>
```

При клике на ссылку, будет переход на скрипт

2.Сделать вызов скрипта через ajax-запрос

```
$("a.money").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $.get( "donate-user.php", function() {
        //alert( "success" );
    })
});
```

Файл **donate-user.php**

```
// Подключение к БД
// $link
...
// Выполнение скрипта
$a = $_SESSION['id'];
$sql = "UPDATE `users` SET `user_balance` = `user_balance` -'$wastedBalance' WHERE `user_id` = $a";
$result = mysqli_query($link, $sql);
$users = mysqli_fetch_all ($result, 1) ;
return $users;
```

Answer (score 1):

Можете использовать такой вариант:

```
<a href="?click=true" class="orange_button money">Подтвердить</a>

<?php
if(isset($_GET['click'])) {
    $a = $_SESSION['id'];
    global $link;
    $sql = "UPDATE `users` SET `user_balance` = `user_balance` -'$wastedBalance' WHERE `user_id` = $a";
    $result = mysqli_query($link, $sql);
    $users = mysqli_fetch_all ($result, 1) ;
    return $users;
}
?>
```

Comment: А теперь помои исправить код, что-бы работало плиз. Через саму БД такой SQL-запрос работает `UPDATE users SET user_balance = user_balance -200 WHERE user_id = 38` а у меня не хочет

Comment: "$wastedBalance" - где переменная?

Comment: @RaZik даже если я просто напишу `$sql = "UPDATE users SET user_balance = user_balance -200 WHERE user_id = 38";` Она не обновляется

Comment: Ошибки есть? приведите var_dump($result)

Comment: @RaZik я нашел ошибку, благодарю

Comment: Рекомендую Вам более точно описывать вопрос и предполагаемый алгоритм решения проблемы. А так же пройти любой онлайн курс php+mysql и html+css+js на начальной сложности для получения базисов. И все такие вопросы сами по себе отпадут. Хорошего дня!

Comment: @RaZik я заметил, что он теперь просто при обновлении страницы списывает деньги со счета, как исправить?)

Comment: а что должно быть?)

Comment: @RaZik при нажатии на кнопку только один раз что-бы списались средства. При повторном нажатии так же что-бы списались а то я обновляю страницу и сразу списывает сколько б я не обновлял. Хотя и ссылка у меня чистая `http://maintest4.ru/pages/profile/donate.php`

Comment: "нажатии на кнопку только один раз что-бы списались средства. При повторном нажатии так же что-бы списались". Обновление страницы == переход по ссылке. Какой способ вызова скрипта?

Comment: @RaZik да, но у меня ссылка чистая `http://maintest4.ru/pages/profile/donate.php` а на кнопке написано `?click=donate` т.е cсылка такого вида должна активировать скрипт `http://maintest4.ru/pages/profile/donate.php?click=donate` т.к  я поставил `if( $_GET['click'] = 'donate')`

Comment: А, ясно, это = являлось виной всему